# SQL percentage on one column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a database, with a column where I have priorities from 1 to 5 and I have column "Category". I want to calculate percentage of each priority group of sum in each category.

Here you can see my database, where I want to get % of priority for each group

Example ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSHq2.png)):

```
+ ------- + ----------- + ------- + -------- + --- + ----------- + ------ + ------- +
| task_id | name        | notes   | priority | med | category    | status | user_id |
+ ------- + ----------- + ------- + -------- + --- + ----------- + ------ + ------- +
| 6       | erhgbrstdhb | rdthbsr | 1        | Yes | Medications | 0      | 1       |
| 13      | rznhrwd     | hbnrnjr | 2        | Yes | Medications | 1      | 1       |
+ ------- + ----------- + ------- + -------- + --- + ----------- + ------ + ------- +
```

For this example I should get:

Priority 1 - Count 1 - % 50

Priority 5 - Count 1 - % 50

What I tried and didn't work ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSHq2.png)):

```
select  priority,
        count(priority) as priority_count,
        count(priority) * 100.0 / (
            select count(*)
                from tasks
        ) as priority_percent
    from tasks
    where category = "Medications"
    group by priority

+ -------- + -------------- + ---------------- +
| priority | priority_count | priority_percent |
+ -------- + -------------- + ---------------- +
| 1        | 1              | 10.0             |
| 5        | 1              | 10.0             |
+ -------- + -------------- + ---------------- +
```

I have trouble with query so any help would be appriciated

Comment: Why you are not adding `where` clause in the subquery, i.e., `select count(*) from tasks WHERE category = 'Medications'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select priority, count(*) as priority_count, 100 * count(*) / (select count(*) from tasks where category = 'medications') as percent
from tasks 
where category = 'Medications'
group by priority
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really put the query in the question as *text*.  That makes it much easier.

I would write this as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.priority,
       COUNT(t.priority) AS priority_count
       ( COUNT(t.priority) /
        (select count(*) from tasks t2 where t2.category = t.category) * 100
       ) as priority_percent
FROM tasks t
WHERE t.category = 'Medications'
GROUP BY t.priority;
```

Your problem is that you are taking the overall `count(*)` from `tasks` rather than those that just match the category.

Comment: You could also do this for "each category" by including category in the group by clause.

Comment: Will remember to put query in text for next time :) Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you sure that your tasks table have only these two lines?
Your query is correct in this context, but if you have more lines that have categories different of "medications", the result will show the percent wrong.
To fix this, add to the next query

`(select count(*) from tasks)`

the filtering by category using `WHERE` clause

`(select count(*) from tasks where category='Medications')`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
priority
,COUNT(priority) AS priority_count
,COUNT(priority)/(select count(*) FROM tasks t1 WHERE t.category = t1.category) * 100 as priority_percent
FROM tasks t
WHERE category = 'Medications'
GROUP BY priority
```

Comment: I get 0 at both "priority_percent" fields

Comment: try adding the WHERE in your count subquery